# How does the following regex works

Tags: regular-expression

I just want to learn how vim regexp works and to be able to compose my own regexp for example, I have found this on google which searches for matching .sh files

```
#^\s\+.*sh$#
```

How does this work?

Comment: For starters there would be chapter 27 of the user manual with about 560 lines. You can reach it with `:h usr_27`. The reference manual on regex is `pattern.txt` which is about 1400 lines with all the details (`:h pattern.txt`). There is also a webpage http://vimregex.com/ named `Vim Regular Expressions 101`.

Comment: @Hotschke That answer wouldn't have helped me 20 yrs ago when I started using VIm, or today. The documentation is not written with the general user in mind it's aimed at people who already have an understanding

Comment: Well, that makes my comment (not an answer) sound stupid. Anyhow: the original title of this question was "Where can I find a comprehensive vim regex tutorial?". I was trying to point out the essentials which statox did not mention. I can agree that understanding a specific regex as a beginner, a general introduction would probably not cover features used in the one you want to understand. IMHO `pattern.txt` is nothing you will totally learn in your life and can be overwhelming for a beginner or everyone. Going through chapter 27 covers a selection of features, i.e. it will not suit everyone.

Comment: @Steve: since you have 20 years of experience. Do you know a beginner friendly vim regex tutorial? BTW a comprehensive tutorial is not realistic. There is a good reason why statox changed the title. How do you learn it?  I am pretty sure alternatives or sharing experiences is appreciated. I can say for myself `pattern.txt` is the vim help page I have opened the most in the past and I do not expect that this will change. It simply takes time to learn it. As Euclid (Elements) said: There is no royal road to geometry / vim / vim regex.

Comment: @Hotschke Unfortunately no. This is a good guide http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/. I learned regex on Sun Unix and Emacs before I saw the light, documentation even worse, but there are reasonable perl style guides. Unfortunately the syntax is different. This was a good help http://vimregex.com/. I just write my own help files so the impenetrable is understandable by me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to know about Vim regex can be found directly in the doc with [`:h regexp`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#regexp). You can read all the file until [`:h perl-patterns`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#perl-patterns), that's a long read but it is worth it.

Now if you read the doc ([`:h pattern-atoms`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#pattern-atoms)) you can find the meaning of the different atom used :

```
#^\s\+.*sh$#
 ^                  The beginning of the line
  \s\+              At least one (\+) whitespace (\s)
      .*            Zero or more (*) character (.), any character
        sh          Literraly the characters 's' then 'h'
          $         The end of the line
```

Note that the `#` character at the beginning and end of the regex were probably used as delimiters in a substitution command like this:

```
%s#^\s\+.*sh$#foo.sh
```

This will rename every `.sh` file name to `foo.sh`, see [`:h :s`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3as) (Note that people often use `;` as delimiters but you can also use `#` or almost any other character)

Comment: @statox Nice answer. As a followup, cause I struggle with it, is how do you do a non greedy regexp for anything, alpha, numeric, whitespace or special

Comment: @Steve I'm not sure I completely understand what you mean. Are you talking of something like `.\{-}` as mentioned at [`:h non-greedy`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#non-greedy)?